# Celery task monitoring inside periodic Task

Tags: task, celery, monitoring, django-celery, periodic-task

I'm using celery inside a django project, i have a celery scheduled task that run every minute and check inside a db if there is a new task to start, and also the task configured has a time start and duration.

The job of this periodic task is:

- Start a new async task if there is a newone configured. (task.delay(...))
- Check if a task previous started is running
- Stop task that exceed its duration (app.control.revoke(...))
- .... and other stuff...

But the question is: What is the "best practice" to monitor the status of started async task inside a periodic task?

I mean everytime the sceduled task run, i get from DB all the configured task (started, to start....) but i don't have the related celery task id associated to it, should i store celery task id inside db, to have the db task associated to the related task celery running?

Could django-celery help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Celery will track status automatically for you using Result Backends. If you want to store this state using Django ORM, then yes django-celery can help with that:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-the-django-orm-cache-as-a-result-backend

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#result-backends

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#task-result-backend-settings

One thing that might also help is Celery has several features for stopping tasks that exceed their duration.

You can use configuration to set global limits:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celeryd-task-time-limit

You can set expiration times per task type using decorator parameters:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#list-of-options

You can set expiration times per scheduled instance:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#expiration

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can i manage these tasks stored inside the result backend inside python script, ad if it is possible where can i find an example? THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: What kinds of things do you mean by "manage" the tasks? In general the result backend is for storing the state of tasks in a database so you can easily query state, get results, check for errors, and build things like status dashboards or historical metrics.